# How to apply/make available my modified Django class-based generic view mixin site-wide?

Tags: python, django, generics, view

In one of my projects Django apps I have a custom mixin that modifies the class-based generic view for date-based objects:

```
class MyCoolMixin(ArchiveIndexView):
    """
    ArchiveIndexView mixin with my customizations
    """
    allow_empty = True
    make_object_list = True
    date_field = 'pub_date'

    # Pass in some custom request vars

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Cool stuff here
        # including getting
        # my context data
        return self.render_to_response(context)

class MyNewArchiveIndexView(MyCoolMixin, ArchiveIndexView):
    pass
```

It works great. So great, in fact, that I want to apply it site-wide rather than just for this specific app. However, in the project layout for Django 1.4 I am not sure where a site-wide class-based generic-view overriding mixin should live. In the root views.py?

```
/path/to/myproject/myproject/views.py
```

And then do I just import that modified generic view in every app I have to ensure it is available?

Additionally, in my various apps models I have different date fields (sometimes it is **pub_date** or **start_date**). Any idea how that should be passed into the mixin so I can override the generic view **date_field** setting?

I am looking for a best practice, and I haven't seen one for the new class-based generic views + mixins.

Comment: Okay - I see that I can add the **date_field** specification in my urls.py when I call the view:

`url(r'^$', MyNewArchiveIndexView.as_view(
    queryset=Model.objects.all(),
    date_field='start_date'
))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could monkey patch ... but that's not a "best practice", it's a hack.

The best practice is to override each urls that use the default ArchiveIndexView with yours. I already [wrote about that in details](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19777151073/how-to-override-a-view-from-an-external-django-app) maybe it'll help.

Comment: Thanks @jpic. Will take a look at your override methods.